# A question about improper integral form $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

In want to calculate the improper integral 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx
$$
As one can show, we have that 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx=1\qquad
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx=-1
$$
Can I deduce that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx=0
$$
or should I first prove that 
$$
\int_{c}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx\qquad
\int_{-\infty}^{c}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx
$$
converges for any arbitrary $c$ and that their sum does not depend upon $c$? Does in general it suffices to verify the converges of the integral for specific $c$? Thanks!

Comment: You only need to show it for one choice of $c$, so since it works for $c=0$ you are Gucci.

Comment: I assume you do not want to put a minus infront of the $|x|$. Then, you can just use symmetry arguments in the first formula. So both your alternatives are correct. Integrals are linear.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-|x|}}dx$ looks infinite.  Did you intend $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx$ or equivalently $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}{x}{e^{-|x|}}dx$ ?

Comment: Thanks @Noah Riggenbach. Does this rule true in general when calculating improper integrals from $(-\infty)$ to $\infty$?

Comment: You right @Henry...Sorry. I fixed that.

Comment: That's a nice $L^1$ function, and it's odd. Any way you slice it, the integral is zero.

Comment: Thanks @Lord Shark. it is true in general to verify it for a specific $c$ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx = -\dfrac{(|b|+1)}{e^{|b|}} + \dfrac{(|a|+1)}{e^{|a|}}$$

and you can let $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to \infty$ independently to get a result of $0$ since each term tends towards $0$.

Your suggestion of adding together $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx=1 \text{ and  } \int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{x}{e^{|x|}}dx=-1$$ is sufficient, providing they are true (and they are)